# How to align an image center in ckeditor 3?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

It appears in the latest available version of ckeditor 3 that there isn't a way to center an image. There is a bug included, but no resolution:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8938

It looks like it hasn't changed on ckeditor 4 beta either.

I was wondering if anyone had any successfully edits of ckeditor 3 to allow centering of images?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Check this post, i posted an easy answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551922/ckeditor-image-align-center-customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is definitely NOT related to ckeditor. The `align` attribute for the `<img>` tag is deprecated as of HTML 4, and removed as of HTML 5.

From the W3C website <sup>[source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html)</sup>:

> The align attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Now, even if the attribute was used in HTML but not in ckeditor - you could see it in the final output (in production, the final website).

There are some different solutions:

- In HTML5, you can use `<center><img ... /></center>` or `<img style="margin:0px auto;display:block" ... />`
- In any HTML version, you can use `<div style="text-align: center;"><img ... /></div>` (or any other tag container like `<p>` `<span>` etc.