# ckeditor image align

Tags: image, alignment, ckeditor, justify

I've done custom image uploader for ckeditor 3.6.4. I insert an image and button "center" for paragraphs dont work for image. In fckeditor I could align image with this button. How to make that work either in cekdtior.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/66892061.jpg/

Comment: Check this post, i posted an easy answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551922/ckeditor-image-align-center-customization

Answer (score -1):

This is because the image must be wrapped in a (psuedo)block element with `text-align: center;` to be centered. There's no other (valid) way to center the image so the Center button is disabled for images. I fact, what you see in FCK was totally wrong, as for such case:

```
<p>Foo<img src="path" />Bar</p>
```

The entire paragraph was centered:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Foo<img src="path" />Bar</p>
```

To sum up: you have to do this manually.

Comment: "Who cares about valid!?" - Valid markup is the essence of what we call standards ;>

Comment: No, standards are for us, the developers. Valid markup would be for the browser, but the browser doesn't care about validity. (That's how HTML5 was born.) Browsers will forever implement `align=`, because they did 10 yrs ago. Good thing too.